# Audited gem without using current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using 'audited' gem changes in model. I do have current_user in my app, but I don't to use it. In fact, I don't want to user track, I just want the changes to be tracked, irrespective who does it. How can I disable current user tracking?
I tried `Audited.current_user_method = :nil`, doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try to set it to nil instead of the symbol :nil? I. e. delete the colon.

Comment: Thanks man. I could never have figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

Im using like this:
create a file into
`Audited.current_user_method = :nil` to ./config/initializers/audited.rb
when Rails launch